How to solve the Poisson equation for the source terms as the double derivative of a spherically symmetric scalar function $\phi$?
I need help understanding how to solve the Poisson equation in 3D for $g_{ij}$, which incorporates the double derivative of a spherically symmetric scalar function $\phi(\textbf{x})$. Where $\textbf{x}$ is the spatial vector in 3D. The expression is given as $ \nabla^2 g_{ij} (\textbf{x}) = \frac{\partial^2\phi (\textbf{x})}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}$. Where $x_i$ & $x_j$ are the spatial coordinates and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} $ is the partial derivative. whereas the solution is given as-
$$g_{ij} (\textbf{x})=\frac{x_ix_j}{r^2} \phi (\textbf{x}) +\left(\delta_{ij}-\frac{3x_ix_j}{r^2}\right)\frac{1}{r^3}\int_0^r k^2\phi(k)dk$$
where $r$ is the radial parameter due to spherical symmetry. The particular solution is given in Weinberg's book- Gravitation and Cosmology in eq 9.9.17, but not the logic. I need a logical explanation of how to derive $g_{ij}$ from the above Poisson equation. Specifically, extracting $x_i x_j$ terms out of the integral while solving for the above Poisson equation.

We can start with finding an ansatz for $g_{ij}$. Note that there are only two rank 2 tensors we can create here: $\delta_{ij}$ and $x_ix_j$ so we know the tensor-structure of $g_{ij}$ has to be on the form $$g_{ij} = A(r) \frac{x_ix_j}{r^2} + B(r)\left(\delta_{ij} - \frac{3x_ix_j}{r^2}\right)$$ for some unknown functions $A$ and $B$. Spherical symmetry means these are functions of $r$ only. The particular form I choose above (instead of $Ax_ix_j + B\delta_{ij}$) is for simplicity as now $A$ is simply the trace of the metric $A \equiv \delta_{ij}g_{ij}$ and $B$ the trace-free part ($B = P_{ij}g_{ij}$ where $P_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}(\delta_{ij} - \frac{x_ix_j}{r^2})$).
Using the PDE we can immediately see that $\nabla^2 \delta_{ij}g_{ij} = \nabla^2\phi$ so $A = \phi$ (up to a constant which we can put to zero).
The main challenge is to determine $B$. One way to do this is to compute the Laplacian of the metric ansatz above:
$$\nabla^2g_{ij} = \left(\delta_{ij}-\frac{3x_ix_j}{r^2}\right)\left[\frac{2(A-3B)}{r^2}+\nabla^2 B\right] + \frac{x_ix_j}{r^2}\nabla^2 A$$
where $\nabla^2 = \frac{d^2}{dr^2} + \frac{2}{r}\frac{d}{dr}$. A quick calculation also gives us
$$\frac{\partial^2 \phi(r)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} = \left(\delta_{ij}-\frac{3x_ix_j}{r^2}\right)\frac{\phi'}{r} + \frac{x_ix_j}{r^2}\nabla^2\phi$$
We can then use the PDE $\nabla^2 g_{ij} = \phi_{,ij}$ to get an ordinary differential equation for $A$ and $B$. This gives us
$$B'' + \frac{2B'}{r} - \frac{6B}{r^2} = \frac{\phi'}{r} - \frac{2\phi}{r^2}$$
Finally, to solve this its useful to introduce $y = (r^3B)' - (r^2\phi)$.

We can also solve this using Fourier transforms, but it requires being fairly familiar with how to manipulate Fourier integrals. Taking the Fourier transform gives us
$$\hat{g}_{ij} = \hat{\phi} \frac{{\bf k}_i{\bf k}_j}{k^2} \implies g_{ij} = \int \frac{d^3{\bf k}}{(2\pi)^3}e^{i{\bf k}\cdot {\bf x}}\hat{\phi} \frac{{\bf k}_i{\bf k}_j}{k^2}$$
where $\hat{\phi}$ only depends on the norm of ${\bf k}$ due to the spherical symmetry.
We can project out $B$ from $g_{ij}$ by applying $P_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}[\delta_{ij}-\frac{x_ix_j}{r^2}]$ which gives us
$$B = P_{ij}g_{ij} = \int \frac{d^3{\bf k}}{2(2\pi)^3}e^{i{\bf k}\cdot {\bf x}}\hat{\phi}(1-\mu^2)$$
where $\mu = ({\bf k}\cdot {\bf x})/k \equiv \cos\theta$ is the cosine of the angle between the two vectors. Placing the ${\bf x}$-vector along the $z$-axis and using $d^3{\bf k} = k^2 dk d\mu d\phi$ then this integral becomes (after performing the trivial $\phi$-integration)
$$B = \int \frac{dk}{2(2\pi)^2}k^2\hat{\phi}\int_{-1}^1 d\mu(1-\mu^2)e^{ikr\mu}$$
Evaluating the $\mu$-integral we obtain
$$r^3B = \int \frac{dk}{2\pi^2}\frac{\hat{\phi}}{k}\left(\sin(kr) - (kr)\cos(kr)\right)$$
Here the trick is to observe that the last term simplifies down to a simple sine when differentiated (this is easier when we know what the answer should be, but probably not so easy to spot otherwise) which gives us
$$(r^3B)' = r^2 \cdot \int \frac{k^2dk}{2\pi^2}\hat{\phi} \frac{\sin(kr)}{kr} \equiv r^2 \phi(r)$$
where we have used the known form for the Fourier transform of a spherically symmetric function.

Finally (just to show that it can be done), we can also solve it using the well-known Poisson integral formula
$$g_{ij}({\bf y}) = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\int d^3{\bf x} \frac{\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}}{|{\bf x} - {\bf y}|} =  -\frac{1}{4\pi}\int d^3{\bf x} \frac{(\delta_{ij}- \frac{3x_ix_j}{r^2})\frac{\phi'}{r}+\frac{x_ix_j}{r^2}(\phi'' + 2\phi'/r)}{|{\bf x} - {\bf y}|}$$
and try to simplify this integral as much as possible. Going to spherical coordinates we get
$$g_{ij}({\bf y}) = -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty dr \int_{-1}^1 d\mu \frac{(\delta_{ij}- \frac{3x_ix_j}{r^2})\phi'r+\frac{x_ix_j}{r^2}(r^2\phi'' + 2\phi'r)}{\sqrt{r^2 + y^2 -2ry\mu }}$$
where $\mu = ({\bf x}\cdot {\bf y})/(ry)$, $r=|{\bf x}|$ and $y=|{\bf y}|$. Applying the same projection operator we used above, $P_{ij}({\bf y}) = (\delta_{ij}-\frac{y_iy_j}{y^2})/2$, we find
$$P_{ij}({\bf y})g_{ij}({\bf y}) = -\frac{1}{4}\int_0^\infty rdr \int_{-1}^1 d\mu \frac{[\phi' + r\phi'']+ [\phi' - r\phi'']\mu^2}{\sqrt{r^2 + y^2 -2ry\mu }}$$
We can also write this as
$$P_{ij}({\bf s})g_{ij}({\bf s}) = -\frac{1}{6}\int_0^\infty dr \int_{-1}^1 d\mu \frac{r(r\phi)''P_0(\mu) - r^3(\phi'/r)'P_2(\mu)}{\sqrt{r^2 + y^2 -2ry\mu }}$$
where $P_0 = 1$ and $P_2 = (3\mu^2-1)/2$ are Legendre polynomials. Now lets use the Laplace expansion
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + y^2 -2ry\mu}} = \frac{1}{\max(r,y)}\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty P_\ell(\mu) \left(\frac{\min(r,y)}{\max(r,y)}\right)^\ell$$
Since the Legendre polynomials are orthogonal, $\int d\mu P_\ell P_\ell' = \frac{2}{2\ell+1}\delta_{\ell\ell'}$, the $\mu$-integral above is easy to evaluate and gives us
$$P_{ij}({\bf s})g_{ij}({\bf y}) = -\frac{1}{3}\int_0^\infty dr \left[(r\phi)''\frac{r}{\max(r,y)} - (\phi'/r)'\frac{r^3\min(r,y)^2}{5\max(r,y)^3}\right]$$
Note that for $r>y$ the integrand is a total derivative (the terms multiplying the $r$-derivatives are constant wrt $r$ so leads to zero when doing IBP). The integral therefore becomes
$$P_{ij}({\bf y})g_{ij}({\bf y}) = -\frac{1}{3}\int_0^y dr \left[(r\phi)''\frac{r}{y} - (\phi'/r)'\frac{r^5}{5y^3}\right]$$
The final part is to perform IBP to move away the $r$-derivatives from $\phi$ to simplify. The first term vanishes as $(r)'' = 0$ and the second one gives us
$$P_{ij}({\bf y})g_{ij}({\bf y}) = \frac{1}{y^3}\int_0^y dr r^2\phi$$
which is the desired result.

Doubt/clarification: In the third equation ($ \frac{∂^2 ϕ(r)}{ ∂x^i ∂x^j} $) of your first response, there should not be a factor of 3 with $x_i x_j$. It should be just $- \frac{x_i x_j}{r^3}$, which changes the final answer. Can you please explain why there should be an extra factor of 3?

This is $-1 = 2-3$. You do get a $-1$, but then $\nabla^2\phi = \phi'' + 2\phi'/r$ has a $+2$ and they combine to give you the $3$. In equations $\phi_{,ij} = \delta_{ij} \phi'/r + x_ix_j/r^2 (\phi'' - \phi'/r) = (\delta_{ij} - 3x_ix_j/r^2) \phi'/r + x_ix_j/r^2 (\phi'' + 2\phi'/r)$

Why not begin by using the Green (or Green's) function for the Laplacian and use integration by parts (in 3-D) to get rid of the derivatives on $\phi$?

@MarkViola You mean the third approach here just doing the IBP right away? I avoided doing it at the start to be able to use the Laplace expansion which makes the angular integral trivial, but yeah I don't see why this shouldn't also work. Haven't looked at it, but might be the integrals are also easy this way.

@Winther Indeed.  And Happy Holidays!

Thanks for providing the solution by using the IBP methods.
In the second way of solving, using Fourier transforms, the definition of $\mu$ should equal $\mu = \frac{\textbf{k}.\textbf{x}}{|k||r|}=cos \theta$. Also, it won't be dimensionally correct otherwise.
